# Can someone help in converting this SQL Server "update statement" to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, sql-server-2008, plsql

```
update a
set a.col1 = 1, 
    a.col2 = 'abc' + CAST(b.colID AS VARCHAR(3))
from #abc a
cross apply 
    (select top 1 x.col3, x.colID1
     from #xyz x
     where (x.col3 = a.col3 and 
            x.colID1 IN (0, 9, 8))) b
```

Table abc and xyz are temp tables that's why the '#'.
Need to convert the above script to Oracle

Comment: What have you tried, and what didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

below link could help you what you want to achive...
https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/private-temporary-tables-18c